# Map controller to an absolute path in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple webapp with a search box visible from all JSP pages.

My controller looks like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request) {
    /*...*/
    return "searchresult";
}
```

In my JSP I use: `<form action="search" method="GET">` in order to make the request. So, for example, if I make a request from `/myproject/index` this works perfect and the resulting URL is `/myproject/search`. But now, if I do the same but from another level, e.g. `/myproject/index/level2`, the resulting URL is `/myproject/index/search` and doesn't work since it doesn't find a controller with that mapping.

What I want to do is to map the controller to an absolute path so, in the second case the resulting URL would be `/myproject/search` and not `/myproject/index/search/`

In my `web.xml` I have this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use EL

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/search" method="GET" />
```

The EL expression will resolve to your application's context path. You then append your full path to it.

Alternatively, the [`core`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) tag lib  provides the `url` tag.

```
<form action="<c:url value="/search" />" method="GET" />
```

That does the same thing, more or less.

Spring  also provides its own `url` tag which you can look into.